# how can i read data from xl sheet or csv based on indentation

Tags: python, csv, xlrd

I have one XL sheet where the data is organised based on spaces like

```
tag     weights    

aaa        1      
 bbb       1      
 ccc       1       
  dddd    -1
  hhhh    1
ddd       1
 bbbb
  fff      1
  hhh      1
 gggg      1
```

The data is like this,col 1 contains tags its indented how i can read the data based on identation. only based on identation i should read it.

And also col2 contains weights "1" stands for "addition" and "-1" stands for "subtraction"

i want output in the form of dict like

```
d={'aaa':'bbb+ccc','ccc':'-dddd+hhhh','ddd':'bbbb+gggg','bbbb':'fff+hhh'}
```

Based on weights that formula is coming for eg 'ccc':'-dddd+hhhh' bcoz dddd has weight '-1' and gggg has weiht '1'

can anyone help me pls

Comment: That wasn't a brilliant decision on someone's part was it? If col1 is quoted " bbb" isn't "bbb", and you can distinguish between the two. As far as I know you are going to have to write the code to convert indent into something meaningful though.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson its not like that,actually "aaa" like values will be the main group,"bbb" and"ccc" will be sub-group in "aaa" and "dddd" is the sub-group under ccc. so when storing i should be able to identify main group and sub-groups.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are describing the way the data looks in excel.  If that's correct, here are two ideas:

1. save the file as csv and use python csv module http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html
2. use http://scienceoss.com/read-excel-files-from-python/ xlrd

From comments below, I should have written:

```
>>> a = '  111'
>>> len(a) - len(a.lstrip())
2
```

Comment: My guess is that the indentation has to do with formatting.  Save the file as csv and post what that looks like

Comment: i saved it in csv format it looks similar like what i posted the question. "aaa" has no space,"bbb" and "ccc" has one space from "aaa" and "dddd" has two space from "aaa".

Comment: I reread your question.  So you are saying that the indentation implies a parent-child relationship?  What is it that you are trying to accomplish ultimately with this dataset

Comment: Their are tags which belongs to some hierarchy in csv, where main group,sub-groups and sub-sub groups are indented so while reading i should be knowing whether i am reading main or sub-grp or sub-sub-grp so i need to read each line based on indentation

Comment: well, if you take len(first_item) - len(strip(first_item)) you can see how many spaces it is indented.  If it is indented more than the previous row, then it is a child of the previous row

Comment: import csv
    for line in open("sss.csv"):
        col=line.split(";")
 a=col[0]
 print len(a[0])-len(strip(a[0]))  But it shows error

Comment: I'm not surprised it "shows error" --- probably a NameError about `strip` which is not a built-in function but a string method, and you should have been advised to use `lstrip` anyway.

Comment: @joelgoldstick now i changed quest can anyone help now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the indentation consists only of spaces (that is, no tabs), you can measure the indentation level by `len(value) - len(value.lstrip())`